# ASP.NET MVC 4: Register Route With Area Folder Name Different From Route Name

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, routes

I'd simply like to configure the location of a registered route versus the convention of using the folder name of the area as the location to find it's views, controllers, ect.

For example; in my mvc 4 web application, I have a folder with path "~/Areas/Orders".  Under the "Orders" area, I have a "HomeController" an "Index()" action and an "Index.cshtml" view file.

However, I want to replace the URL route to the "Orders" area with "O" without changing the name of the "Orders" folder.  So a client using my site would browse to "www.mysite.com/O/Home/Index" instead of "www.mysite.com/Orders/Home/Index"

Any advice would be appreciate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to just change the route like this in your `AreaRegistration`

```
context.MapRoute("Orders_default",
                "o/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                new {action = "Index", area = "Orders", id = UrlParameter.Optional});
```

Comment: Thanks @mmillican. I tried this, but doing so means all my files (controllers, views) must be placed under a folder named "O". Whereas, I would like to put them in a folder called "orders" and have the area named "O".

Comment: I updated the code to add ` area = "Orders"`.  Give that a shot and let me know if it helps.

Comment: CHA-CHING! That was it! Thanks again @mmillican :-)